# Create a matrix m and set to the positions mij = (i+j)*10

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to create a Matrix 5x5 and give to each position of the matrix the value, given the following mij = (i+j)*10.

For example in 1,1 it would be, (1+1)*10 = 20

```
Matrix:
20  30  40  50  60

30  ...

40  ...

50  ...

60  ...
```

In general, I do not know how can I involve the indexes of the rows and columns when creating the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another base R solution besides [`outer` approach by @user2974951](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60336912/12158757)

```
n <- 5
mat <-(t(replicate(n,seq(n)))+seq(n))*10
```

such that

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   20   30   40   50   60
[2,]   30   40   50   60   70
[3,]   40   50   60   70   80
[4,]   50   60   70   80   90
[5,]   60   70   80   90  100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> outer(1:5,1:5,"+")*10

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   20   30   40   50   60
[2,]   30   40   50   60   70
[3,]   40   50   60   70   80
[4,]   50   60   70   80   90
[5,]   60   70   80   90  100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive solution:

```
i <- 4
j <- 5
(matrix(1:j, i, j, byrow = TRUE) + matrix(1:i, i, j)) * 10
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   20   30   40   50   60
[2,]   30   40   50   60   70
[3,]   40   50   60   70   80
[4,]   50   60   70   80   90
```